# Use one iPhone to call a method on another iPhone

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

My app uses objective c , AFNetworking, J son, and php to let users register, login, take, and upload photos to a UIScrollView as Jpeg thumbs. Everything in the app is referenced and stored either programmatically or in the database i.e. usernames, user ids, and photo ids. The app uses 5 php functions (register, login, upload, logout, stream) which are called using the following command which is part of a class that subclasses `AFHTTPClient` in AFNetworking.

```
-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock;
```

When a photo is tapped the stream command is called to show the user a fullscreen version of the thumbnail. Also a segue takes the user to a new ViewController.

My goal is to take a picture on the iPhone that uploaded the picture that was tapped by scaling my existing API. How do I do this?

**Edit** Update in progress...

Comment: You will need to establish some sort of network connection between the two devices - either via Bluetooth or TCP/IP - and then send some sort of command over that connection to trigger the the capture.  You can't simply invoke a method on an object in an app running on another device

Comment: What would you suggest? I can't use bluetooth because there isn't enough range and I would also need help setting up this command with my existing api...Id be open to any frameworks or sample projects

Comment: Where are the two devices in relation to each other?  If they are on the same network then one can listen on a network socket and the other can connect.  If they are on different networks then you are going to have to coordinate through your server some how.

Comment: So far they are running on the same mamp local server. same host same web path etc

Comment: do you mean physically? Yes right now I am testing them side by side but eventually this method/algorithm would have to still work even if one was in china. I will add some more explaining the API method

Comment: any suggestions? Also in your opinion (seeing as I will probably have to ask this question again and again) was my first post too much code? And does the new question do a better job describing what I want, or was the old one better?

Comment: There was a lot of code in your first question and the edit is better, but unfortunately your question is probably still too broad.  Essentially you will need to find some way for your two apps to communicate via your server.  The app that wants the photo taken will need to send a message to the server to that effect and then the server will need to identify if the corresponding user is currently online with the app open and then send a message to that app using something a web socket or a push notification.  This whole process is too big to receive an answer

Comment: If i make a github repository that simply explains everything from the database to the code  I think it would be easier to collaborate and solve this riddle. What about you? I will create one now and will update when I've posted it.

Comment: just uploaded the repository =) I agree with your logic 'need to find a way for devices to communicate via the server' https://github.com/tonycrencren/Hack-a-pic- need a little more help to execute that functionality.

Comment: uploading all that code in that repo forced me to think about the app in a easier much simpler way, i think I've got it down now; will update with progress....

Comment: I suggest you can use remote push notification, though the size has limits (2KB for iOS8+ & OS X, 256 bytes otherwise). By opening the push notification, you can initiate some actions, such as socket connection, etc. All you need is to pass the link information to your destination phone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Raptor. I think remote push notifications could be very interesting. I will do some more research on it and read the documentation. update in progress.

Comment: @raptor, thanks again for your suggestion ; after reading the documentation I will ask another question on stack but might as well start with this one: can the remote push notification trigger the method/function I need without any user interaction on the device the notification goes to (I think this is called the device token)?

Comment: Since iOS 7, it is possible with [Silent Push Notification](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/).